# Security Sandbox Violation Flash Twitter API - as3-application-only library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security, twitter

I'm using https://github.com/denisdanielyan/as3-Application-Only-Twitter to access tweets via a Flash app.

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: Timeout on xmlsocket://api.twitter.com:843 (at 3 seconds) while waiting for socket policy file.  This should not cause any problems, but see www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for an explanation.

```
 *** Security Sandbox Violation *** Connection to api.twitter.com:443 halted
 - not permitted from http://mywebsite.com/myswf.swf Error:
 Request for resource at xmlsocket://api.twitter.com:443 by requestor
 from http://http://mywebsite.com/myswf.swf is denied due to lack of
 policy file permissions.
```

I assume it's something to do with the crossdomain file, which I've specified

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://mywebsite.com/crossdomain.xml");

<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Anyone any clues?

Comment: I think the policy file being loaded is this one: https://twitter.com/crossdomain.xml I don't see why Twitter will connect to your host :)

Comment: Thanks. This type of library is quite common and works for lots of other people, so I imagine it's something else.

Comment: Hm, have you tried running it from a web server instead of .swf? At least you will be able to check the requests/responses that are being done..

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the solution http://www.blog.lessrain.com/as3-java-socket-connections-to-ports-below-1024/

Comment: Ah I always forget that :) Glad that worked out! You could answer your own question and close it, so it won't stay opened.

Comment: I don't know if it's the answer yet.. I'm struggling to get the service started. Will answer the question once I know.